# A get this error "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'components' of 'object null' as it is null."

Tags: object, null, next.js, components, typeerror

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'components' of 'object null' as it is null. When I run "yarn dev" to my Next.js  project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check the children of `_app.js` file. First render it with a dummy tag and after that pass your actual data

Comment: Check the children for what exactly?